# Primitive elements of polynomial

Tags: polynomials

**Problem:**

Given a primitive polynomial $f(x)$ over $\mathbb F_2$ of degree 248,

a) is $g(x) = x^{17}$ a primitive element? Why?

b) is $h(x) = x^{23}$ a primitive element? Why?

**Progress:**

I'm thinking that the element must be coprime to the order of the group, which here is $2^{248}-1$.

I.e. $\gcd(2^{248}-1, x^{17}) = 1 \iff x^{17}$ is a primitive element.

But does it even make sense to find $\gcd(2^{248}-1, x^{17})$?

P.s., feel free to edit tags. The context is cryptography, but it seems irrelevant to the problem at hand, and I can't think of any other useful tags.

**EDIT - More progress:**

For a) I was hinted to show that 17 divides the order of $x$ which is $2^{248} -1$, which I can do. But why does this show that $x^{17}$ is not a primitive element?